# How to use tibco on event timeout starter process?

Tags: tibco, businessworks

I am doing some POC's in tibco general palletes and came across `onEventTimeout`.By reading the [docs](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/activematrix_businessworks/5.12.0/doc/html/tib_bw_palette_reference/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm#context=tib_bw_palette_reference&file=palref.5.056.htm) it says

*The On Event Timeout process starter specifies a process to execute when a Wait For ... activity discards an incoming event due to a timeout. A Wait For ... activity’s event timeout is specified by the Event Timeout field on the Event tab of the activity.*

So I created one process definition having start,wait and end activity.Then created another process definition and added oneventtimeout starter process from the general activities.Now when I click on event source browse button(binocular icon) then it does not show me the above process definiton(having wait activity).So I guess I may be missing something.

Can any body please tell me how to use it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onEventTimeout` process starter will not work with a `Wait` activity. Try using a "Wait for" type of activity instead, for instance `Wait for JMS Queue Message`.